# Change variable value for the first row group_by subject ID using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

More than 2,000 subjects. I would like to change the value for 'time2' to 0 for each first row by subject. For instance, ID=2 subject has 1 for 'time2' at first row of this subject. How to change it to 0, considering 2k subjects?

```
ID    time1  time2   
 1      0     0
 1      0     1
 1      1     5
 2      0     1
 2      1     3
 2      3     5
 3   ....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can use `ifelse` based on a logical condition with `row_number()`

```
df2 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(time2 = ifelse(row_number()==1, 0, time2))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: ID [2]
#     ID time1 time2
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     0     0
#2     1     0     1
#3     1     1     5
#4     2     0     0
#5     2     1     3
#6     2     3     5
```

---

Or using `data.table`, create a row index (`.I`) grouped by 'ID' and assign (`:=`) those elements in 'time2' that corresponds to the row index to 0

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df2[, .I[seq_len(.N)==1] , ID]$V1, time2 := 0][]
#    ID time1 time2
#1:  1     0     0
#2:  1     0     1
#3:  1     1     5
#4:  2     0     0
#5:  2     1     3
#6:  2     3     5
```

---

Or a compact `base R` option would be (assuming that 'ID' is `order`ed)

```
df$time2[!duplicated(df$ID)] <- 0
df
#   ID time1 time2
#1  1     0     0
#2  1     0     1
#3  1     1     5
#4  2     0     0
#5  2     1     3
#6  2     3     5
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `dplyr` in combination with `replace`:

```
df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(time2 = replace(time2, 1, 0))
# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: ID [2]
# 
#      ID time1 time2
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     0     0
# 2     1     0     1
# 3     1     1     5
# 4     2     0     0
# 5     2     1     3
# 6     2     3     5
```